# Error in ROR 3 app integration in facebook Login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

I am first time integrating facebook login to ROR app for that I am using following [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-omniauth-to-authenticate-your-users/)  after creating omniauth.rb file in initializes I try to run 
this(`rails generate controller sessions new create failure`) command in terminal I got an error:

The code in omniauth.rb file is:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 123432432433, 1233443232342432432
end
```

T'm getting this error:

```
omniauth-tutorial/config/initializers/omniauth.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:556
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:555
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/bilmailid17/appror/omniauth-tutorial/config/environment.rb:5
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:22
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Comment: check this out <a> http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/ </a>

Comment: Try to put key and secret between quotes (")

Comment: As a good SO user, you should accept some of answers for your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting quotes around your APP_ID and APP_SECRET:

> provider :facebook, "123432432433", "1233443232342432432"